# Apache virtualhosts not going

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualization

I have an AWS virtual server, with ubuntu 14.04 and apache 2.4.7. I have two domain names (let's say name1.com and name2.com), and I wanted both them to point to the IP of the server, and that apache redirected automatically to the folders (lets say /var/www/html/name1 and /var/www/html/name2 ).

Both sites are avalaible under `http://ip-server/name1` and `http://ip-server/name2`.

I follow the usual instructions: In `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`  I copy `000-default.conf` to `001-name1.conf`. This is the content of the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName name1.com
    ServerAlias www.name1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/name1
    LogLevel error
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/name1.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/name1.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I activate it with `sudo a2ensite 001-name1.conf`, and restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`.

But when I try `http://name1.com` (in a new private-mode brownser to avoid cache), it still redirects me to the defect `index.html` of apache.

When I run `apache2ctl -S` I get:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
   *:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost ip--x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost name1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-name1.conf:1)
             alias www.name1.com
```

The logs are empty, so I don't know what else to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Start by disabling the default site (`sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`).  If you're not serving content there, then remove it.

The order in which sites are loaded matters (that's why default is prefixed with 000). The default site will be the first .conf loaded (based on alphabetical ordering).  If you have `ServerName` set in your default.conf, then it will respond regardless of the vHosts that come after it.

Once you disable the default site, bounce apache, and comment below if it doesn't work.  we'll try something else.

Comment: OK, so I disabled de default site and added 002-name2.conf with the parameters of the 2nd site. The problems now are:  1) The Wordpress site under name1 has lost the style. Probably related with the Mysql db, that keeps pointing to the ip-server.  2) Pointing to `http://site2.com` shows nothing.  3) Other content that was available under 'http://ip-server/anotherfolder', now is not avalaible. I had tried moving `000-default.conf`to `003-default.conf`, but no change.

Comment: The content of `apache2ctl` is <br/>  VirtualHost configuration:
    *:80  is a NameVirtualHost
    default server name1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-name1.conf:1)
    port 80 namevhost name1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-nam1.conf:1)
                 alias www.name1.com
         port 80 namevhost name2.eu (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-name2.conf:1)
                 alias www.name2.eu
         port 80 namevhost ip-server (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/003-default.conf:1)
    ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
    Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"